# Relocate filters on an Excel worksheet with a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

In my worksheet where I have my pivot table I have many different filters to chose between.

To the eye it doesn't really look nice and I want to be able to maybe split that long list of filters into a few shorter ones. But I can't figure out how to do this. I've seen where I can move the whole pivot table, but then it's all included and as one piece that can't be split.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2010 you have an option to "replace" filters with Slicers.  You can choose the slicer in the Pivot Table's Options Tab (Sort & Filter group).  Slicers can be moved and formatted much easier than traditional pivot filters. They also have an extra advantage of being able to feed multiple Pivot Tables with the same filtering.

Note:  If you're using Powerpivot, slicers are built into the Pivot Table Field List, making them even easier to get to and use.

Comment: thanks for reply! yeah i know about slicers n am using them two filter some variables that i want to go trough all the pivot tables....and i know they are possible to be moved etc...but still want to use the "normal" filters....so im guessing u dont know, if even possible, how to relocate the traditional filters on the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Take a normal PivotTable with multiple Report Filters (In this example – Region, Product Description, Business Segment, Customer Name).

Right click anywhere inside the PivotTable and select PivotTable options.

In the Options dialog box, you’ll see a setting called ‘Report filter fields per column’.

Change this setting to specify the number of filter fields you’d like to have in each column. In this example, I’d like break up my Report filters so that only two are showing in each column.

Once implemented, the Report filters are broken out so that only two show up in each column.

This is a nice feature if you want your Report filters conform to the general shape of your PivotTable.

Here is a PivotTable where the Report filters are set to show only one per column.

Comment: What example are you referring to? Please edit your answer to include the example.